# Shuffle failed on empty file. EOFException: Unexpected end of input stream

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to run copy of data processing pipeline, that correctly working on cluster, on local machine with hadoop and hbase working in standalone mode.
Pipeline contains few mapreduce jobs starting one after another and one of these jobs has mapper that does not write anything in output (depends on input, but it does not write anything in my test), but has reducer.
I receive this exception during this job running:

```
16:42:19,322 [INFO] [localfetcher#13] o.a.h.i.c.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.gz] 
16:42:19,322 [INFO] [localfetcher#13] o.a.h.m.t.r.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#13 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local509755465_0013_m_000000_0 decomp: 2 len: 6 to MEMORY
16:42:19,326 [WARN] [Thread-4749] o.a.h.m.LocalJobRunner: job_local509755465_0013 java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in localfetcher#13
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462) ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.5.1.jar:?]
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529) [hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.5.1.jar:?]
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in localfetcher#13
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:134) ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3.jar:?]
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:376) ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3.jar:?]
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319) ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.5.1.jar:?]
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of input stream
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:145) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar:?]
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:85) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar:?]
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:199) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar:?]
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.InMemoryMapOutput.shuffle(InMemoryMapOutput.java:97) ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3.jar:?]
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher.copyMapOutput(LocalFetcher.java:157) ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3.jar:?]
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher.doCopy(LocalFetcher.java:102) ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3.jar:?]
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher.run(LocalFetcher.java:85) ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3.jar:?]
```

I checked files produced by mapper and I expected that they will be empty because mapper does not write anything to store, but they contain strange text:

File: /tmp/hadoop-egorkiruhin/mapred/local/localRunner/egorkiruhin/jobcache/job_local509755465_0013/attempt_local509755465_0013_m_000000_0/output/file.out

> ÿÿÿÿ^@^@

File: /tmp/hadoop-egorkiruhin/mapred/local/localRunner/egorkiruhin/jobcache/job_local509755465_0013/attempt_local509755465_0013_m_000000_0/output/file.out.index

> ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^F^@^@^@^@dTG<93>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an explanation for this problem, but I solved it by turning off compression of mapper output:

```
config.set("mapreduce.map.output.compress", "false");
```